# Can I do something with this OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning?

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, intellij-idea, openjdk-17

When I run Spring Boot application I get this warning:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify
> were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future
> release.

Is there something I can do to remove that warning?

Comment: It's just a warning that these options will be removed in the future.

Comment: If you are seeing those messages, you are NOT running your application using OpenJDK 11 ... as the question tag implies.  Please correct the tag.